# Django MySQL IntegrityError: ("Field 'created_at' doesn't have a default value")

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am new to Django.

```
IntegrityError: (1364, "Field 'created_at' doesn't have a default value")
```

occurred when I didn't write `created_at` for models I defined at models.py.

Every time I face such error, I add

`created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)`

to models.py and then run `python manage.py makemigrations; python manage.py migrate --fake`.

Is that OK? (I mean, does it follow Django best practice or not? )
When I was using Rails, I've never faced such issues. Why doesn't Django automatically handle `created_at` column?

Also, I'd like to know why `--fake` option removes this error.

### version

```
Django==1.11.5 
mysqlclient==1.3.12                                                                                                                                                                                                
Python 3.6.1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best practice is to run `python manage.py makemigrations app_label` and `python manage.py migrate app_label` after every change in the `models.py`. The option `--fake` marks the migration as completed without actually executing the SQL code to change the database schema.

Comment: @cezar thanks, your explanation of `--fake` is easy to understand. If I run migration commands after every change, `"Field 'created_at' doesn't have a default value"` doesn't happen?

Comment: It's hard to say from here how this problem has sneaked into your code. Did you create a model class and later added the field `created_at` to it?

Comment: @cezar Yes, because I was accustomed to Rails-style, I forgot to define `created_at` column at the first time, and added this clumn after migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments I think I can reproduce your steps. You had a model class in your `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class YourModel(models.Model):
    one_field = models.CharField()
    another_field = models.CharField()
```

Then you ran:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

After that you added to your model class:

```
from django.db import models

class YourModel(models.Model):
    one_field = models.CharField()
    another_field = models.CharField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)
```

but forgot to run the migrations and got the error message.

This is because Django ORM is looking for the property `created_at`, which it can't find in the DB.
You have to run the commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

again. Remember that the option `--fake` won't change the DB. It just marks the migration as run. Use it only when you're sure what are you doing.

As Johannes Reichard has suggested you should better use `auto_now_add` (and there is also `auto_now`) for this purpose. Check the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#datefield).

The drawback is that this field won't be shown in the admin. A workaround is to overwrite the save method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        self.created_at = timezone.now() # import it from django.utils
    super(YourModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you want to have an attribute `created_at` which is set on every creation of a model instance. There is an easier way for that:

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here the docs explaining it in detail https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered similar issue, where my DB state was out of sync with the repository (probably some leftover fields remained in DB from migrations from another repository branch).

I was getting crazy seeing this error:

`IntegrityError: (1364, "Field 'open' doesn't have a default value")`

when I did not have field `open` in my model.

Make sure to inspect your DB schema and look for table definitions, then compare it with your Django model definitions.